# Trying to run vpython code in Anaconda IDE, error with "visual" module

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, anaconda, vpython

I am using on windows 7 64 bit the Anaconda IDE for Python 2.7. I need to start using Vpython so I installed it from the official site of Anaconda https://www.continuum.io/downloads .
Whenever I try to run some code and using the `from visual import *` command it returns an error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X7LH.jpg)

The installed packages are these:

runfile('C:/Users/Dimitris/Desktop/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Dimitris/Desktop')
['alabaster', 'anaconda-client', 'argcomplete', 'astropy', 'babel', 'backports-abc', 'backports.ssl-match-hostname', 'beautifulsoup4', 'bitarray', 'blaze', 'bokeh', 'boto', 'bottleneck', 'cdecimal', 'cffi',
 'clyent', 'colorama', 'comtypes', 'conda', 'conda-build', 'conda-env', 'configobj', 'cryptography', 'cycler', 'cython', 'cytoolz', 'datashape', 'decorator', 'docutils', 'enum34', 'et-xmlfile', 'fastcache',
 'flask', 'funcsigs', 'futures', 'gevent', 'gevent-websocket', 'greenlet', 'grin', 'h5py', 'idna', 'ipaddress', 'ipykernel', 'ipython', 'ipython-genutils', 'ipywidgets', 'itsdangerous', 'jdcal', 'jedi', 
'jinja2', 'jsonschema', 'jupyter', 'jupyter-client', 'jupyter-console', 'jupyter-core', 'llvmlite', 'lxml', 'markupsafe', 'matplotlib', 'menuinst', 'mistune', 'multipledispatch', 'nbconvert', 'nbformat',
 'networkx', 'nltk', 'nose', 'notebook', 'numba', 'numexpr', 'numpy', 'odo', 'openpyxl', 'pandas', 'path.py', 'patsy', 'pep8', 'pickleshare', 'pillow', 'pip', 'ply', 'psutil', 'py', 'pyasn1', 'pycosat',
 'pycparser', 'pycrypto', 'pyflakes', 'pygments', 'pyopenssl', 'pyparsing', 'pyreadline', 'pytest', 'python-dateutil', 'pytz', 'pywin32', 'pyyaml', 'pyzmq', 'qtconsole', 'requests', 'rope', 'scikit-image',
 'scikit-learn', 'scipy', 'setuptools', 'simplegeneric', 'singledispatch', 'six', 'snowballstemmer', 'sockjs-tornado', 'sphinx', 'sphinx-rtd-theme', 'spyder', 'sqlalchemy', 'statsmodels', 'sympy', 'tables', 
'toolz', 'tornado', 'traitlets', 'unicodecsv', 'vpnotebook', 'vpython', 'werkzeug', 'wheel', 'xlrd', 'xlsxwriter', 'xlwings', 'xlwt']

I would appreciate every help.
Thank you.